# Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Account Number: Error: 'Account Number' cannot be found in the system

Tags: acumatica

The field that needs to save the record ID has an issue with resolving the autonumbering.

The DAC is set up to use autonumbering. However, when searching for a record or creating a new record, I get a 'The item AcctCD is not found (restricted:False,external:True,value: )' error

DAC:

```cs
    [SerializableAttribute()]
    [PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(LoanMaint))]
    [PXCacheName("OLAccount")]
    public class OLAccount : IBqlTable
    {   
 [PXDBString(30, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Loan Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, TabOrder = 1)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<OLAccount.acctCD>))]
         [LoanAccount.RefNbr(typeof(Search2<OLAccount.acctCD, 
                                      InnerJoin<BAccountR, On<OLAccount.parentBAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>>), 
                                      Filterable = true, IsPrimaryViewCompatible = true)]       
        [LoanAccount.Numbering()]
        public virtual string AcctCD { get; set; }
        public abstract class acctCD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<acctCD> { }
}

public class LoanAccount
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Specialized selector for OLAccount AcctCD.<br/>
        /// By default, defines the following set of columns for the selector:<br/>
        /// OLAccount.acctCD, OLAccount.acctName, OLAccount.externalAccountRef, <br/>
        /// OLAccount.externalReference, OLAccount.parentBAccountID<br/>
        /// </summary>
        public class RefNbrAttribute : PXSelectorAttribute
        {
            public RefNbrAttribute(Type SearchType)
                : base(SearchType,
                typeof(OLAccount.acctCD),
                typeof(OLAccount.acctName),
                typeof(OLAccount.externalAccountRef),
                typeof(OLAccount.parentBAccountID),
                typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
                typeof(BAccountR.acctName),
                typeof(BAccountR.type),
                typeof(BAccountR.classID))
            {
            }
        }

        public class NumberingAttribute : AutoNumberAttribute
        {
            public NumberingAttribute()
                : base(typeof(OLSetup.accountNumberingID), typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate)) { }

        }
    }
```

Graph:

```cs
public class LoanMaint : PXGraph<LoanMaint, OLAccount>
    {
        public PXSelect<OLAccount> LoanAccount;
        public PXSelect<OLAccount, Where<OLAccount.acctCD, Equal<Current<OLAccount.acctCD>>>> CurrentLoanAccount;

        public PXSetup<Company> Company;
        public PXSetup<OLSetup> OLSetup;

        public LoanMaint()
        {
            OLSetup setup = OLSetup.Current;
        }
    }
```

[Error screen on system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBPbV.png)

Comment: Is this error shown if you remove PXSelectorAttribute or RefNbrAttribute ? I remember some bad behavior related to the AccessInfo.businessDate, can you try to add the Date field to your DAC and map RefNumber to it?

Comment: Hi Samvel, thought as much but still an issue even if I use the record date. Like orders

Comment: Have you tried to remove the PXSelectorAttribute and leave only RefNbrAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing ReferentialIntegrity Attributes, refer to link form more information: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/08/using-of-pxrestrictorattribute.html, the same error I was getting for no reason: *It gives the uninformative message  cannot be found in the system if a record with a given key does not meet the selector condition*

Answer (score 1):

I replicated this without receiving any errors.

Try this:

- In the **DAC** definition, remove the *PXSelector* attribute (the selector is already being added by *LoanAccount.RefNbr()*)
- There is a mismatch between the field's length (30 chars) and the number of characters in the mask (only 15 "C" were added). Change the field's length to 15 (most of Acumatica auto-numbered fields support up to 15 chars)

If these changes still throw the error. To troubleshoot, simplify the code with:

a. Use an Acumatica numbering sequence: i.e. *APSetup.batchNumberingID* instead of *OLSetup.accountNumberingID*

b. Simplify the RefNbr() query to use a single table (or change it to a LeftJoin<> rather than an InnerJoin<>)

Comment: Hi Fernando, the DAC PXSelector & 15 chars was a mistake on my part when I copied over, both those items are in order. I even simplified the select to only look at the one table. What is odd is that it cannot find the field and not value. As if the DB Column does not exist. even though it is selectable in the screen design and visible on SQL Selects. I even created a new site and database, published to there and same issue

Comment: @Gerhard-ZA Did you create the table on the SQL side manually? If so, could you confirmed if the field was created as nvarchar(15)?

Comment: Hi Fernando, yes the field was created as nvarchar(15)

Comment: @Gerhard-ZA when you open the page, does the autonumber field show <NEW> or <SELECT>?

Comment: Hi Fernando, yes. The frustration is the process taken is exactly to the T on how we do all other screens, yet this one has an issue. it shows a <NEW> as set on the auto numbering placeholder

Comment: Would you like to connect via GTM? Email me to famadoz@skyknack.com and let's see if we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with **PXSelectorAttribute**, and **PXRestrictors** doesn't help.

Try to place your DAC's keys field in the same order as at database table constraint.

For example:

```
CONSTRAINT [SOLine_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyID] ASC,
    [OrderType] ASC,
    [OrderNbr] ASC,
    [LineNbr] ASC
)
```

in a DAC:

```
#region OrderType
...
#endregion

#region OrderNbr
...
#endregion

#region LineNbr
...
#endregion
```

It helps me in my case

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten a little different error:

*An error occurred during processing of the field Account value 59000 GL Error: Account is inactive.*

[image]

I solved that by putting the **Active** the account on Chart Of Accounts (GL202500) screen.